# train a language model using Google Ngrams

Tags: python, nlp, nltk, n-gram

I want to find a conditional probability of a word given its previous set of words. I plan to use `Google N-grams` for the same. However, being such a huge resource as it is, I don't think it is computationally possible to do on my PC. ( To process all N-grams, to train a language model).

So is there any way I can train a language model using Google Ngrams ? (Even `python NLTK` library does not support `ngram` language model anymore)
Note - I know that a language model can be trained using ngrams, but given the vast size of Google N grams, how can a language model be trained using specifically Google ngrams?

Comment: Is your question whether it's possible to use Google N-grams to train or a model or is it how to train an language model with ngrams or both?

Comment: how to train a language model with ngrams

Comment: http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/feature_extraction.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You ought to check out this slick code base from UC Berkley: https://github.com/adampauls/berkeleylm

In the `examples/` folder, you will find a bash script `make-binary-from-google.sh` that creates a compact language model from the raw Google N-Grams. The resulting LM implements stupid backoff and utilizes a fast and efficient data structure described in the following paper: http://nlp.cs.berkeley.edu/pubs/Pauls-Klein_2011_LM_paper.pdf

If you are just interested in the final trained LM, you can download it in a variety of languages from the Berkley-hosted website: http://tomato.banatao.berkeley.edu:8080/berkeleylm_binaries/

Comment: Hi, I tried running `java -ea -mx10000m -server -cp ../src edu.berkeley.nlp.lm.io.ComputeLogProbabilityOfTextStream -g vocab_cs.gz eng.blm.gz <file to be scored>` where I downloaded `eng.blm.gz` and `vocab_cs.gz` from the provided link. However, I'm getting all the logProbs as `Nan`s. Can you point out what might be the problem here?